How to detect a DataContext of DataGridRow for DataGridTemplateColumn?
We are working on WPF app development. And one of our dialogs has a DataGrid with custom columns.
We have one custom column class that inherits a DataGridTemplateColumn:
public class MultiEditComboBoxColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", 
        typeof(IEnumerable), 
        typeof(MultiEditComboBoxColumn), 
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged)));
}

This column generates a dynamic template with combobox. Also, it has some customs events and a lot of custom backend logic. So that's why we don't use a default DataGridComboboxColumn.
To set some collection for this dynamic combobox we created a Dependency Property "ItemsSource" and bind it to "ItemsSource" property of the internal dynamic combobox.
So when we have some DataGrid and use our MultiEditComboBoxColumn inside - we can pass some collection to this property.
In our project, we have one dialog "MainView" and "MainViewModel" for it. This dialog has a DataGrid with MultiEditComboBoxColumn column. "MainViewModel" has some collection that are related to DataGrid. This collection contains a few objects of "PointViewModel" type that represent each row in DataGrid. "PointViewModel" has the property "AvailablePointTypes" - a list of strings. Each "PointViewModel" can have different values in this list. And I want to set this list to "ItemsSource" property of MultiEditComboBoxColumn:
public class PointViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public List<string> AvailablePointTypes { get; }

    public PointViewModel()
    {
        AvailablePointTypes = GetAvailablePointTypes();
    }

    private List<string> GetAvailablePointTypes()
    {
        // Get a list of available point types with different values for each PointViewModel object.
        ...
    }
}


public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public List<PointViewModel> Points { get; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Points = ReadPoints();
    }

    private List<PointViewModel> ReadPoints()
    {
        // Get a collection of points to display in DataGrid.
        ...
    }
}

And here is how I try to set this collection to our custom column:
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Points}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        // Other columns ...
        <MultiEditComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding AvailablePointTypes}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

But it doesn't work. When I run the app I see an error:
Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for the target element. BindingExpression:Path=AvailablePointTypes; DataItem=null; target element is 'MultiEditComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=29829272); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
It seems that it is unable to detect a DataContext of row in this column where I clicked on dynamic combobox. So that's why I see my combobox in the UI but it's always empty.
How can I fix that correctly?

A DataGridColumn is not part of the visual tree and doesn't inherit any DataContext.
A common solution to this issue is to use a Freezable that captures the DataContext as explained and exemplified  here:
<DataGridTextColumn ... Visibility="{Binding Data.SomeProperty, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>

Or you could create a default CellTemplate that simply binds a ComboBox to some property that you specify dynamically.

Thanks for the answer. In our solution, I can't create a CellTemplate in the XAML code. For our goals, we generate it dynamically inside MultiEditComboBoxColumn class. So that's not our way.
BindingProxy was one of my checks. But the main problem is that when I use it - "Data" actually has a DataContext of MainViewModel, not a PointViewModel. So it's unable to find a AvailablePointTypes property.

Did you see my edit: Or you could create a default CellTemplate that simply binds a ComboBox to some property that you specify dynamically.. You should go with this option then.

Your dependency property should probably be a string that specifies a path to bind to, or a BindingBase. That's how  the Binding property is implemented in the DataGridBoundColumn class.

Yes. But in my case, it didn't help. Because this MultiEditComboBoxColumn could be used in cases when I have a static collection in MainViewModel or some collection in PointViewModel. And both of them should use different ways. So I just created a copy of the backend logic in my backend code of dialog.
